# If I make a 100% OpenGL-based user interface in Android or iOS, is it possible to embed a Google Map widget in it?

Tags: android, ios, android-layout, opengl-es, android-widget

I've never done such a thing before. The reason I ask is because I'm contemplating on making my own user interface using OpenGL so that it is cross platform on Android, iOS, etc. By doing  so I will avoid the cross platform issues people face when making a cross-platform app that uses native widgets on the different devices. The HTML5/JavaScript solutions provided by frameworks like PhoneGap or Appcelerator are sluggish and clunky. HTML5/JavaScript performance just doesn't compare to OpenGL and native widget performance.

So my question is (and I'm betting it might be a simple one): If I have my own user interface powered by OpenGL, can I embed a native widget in it if I need to (namely an Android or iOS Google Map widget)?

I'm planning on minimizing the use of native widgets, but obviously a Google Map widget would be a little to difficult to create compared to a simple button or text field. It's my guess that perhaps calls can be made to Android or iOS functions that can overlay a widget view on top of my interface. Is that a good guess?

Comment: I can not answer for Android but with iOS there is no problem mixing UIKit (native controls) and OpenGL/ES drawn stuff.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. Apple has spent hundreds millions of dollars over the last 25 years (CocoaTouch is that old) paying programmers to design good user interface widgets, and is improving it all the time, and you want to throw that away and start again? It will take you six months just to make a good text input field. Two weeks to make a button that responds properly to touch events. Write custom interface code for each platform or don't bother writing an app at all.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert You are correct, it may take more time to start from scratch, but there are nice frameworks out there (free and open-source) such as Kivy, Qt Quick, HaxeNME, and MoSync to help in the process of making OpenGL-powered interfaces. Besides, if my app were to have it's own amazing look and feel across platforms, then that (in my humble opinion) would make my app even better, more distinguished, and more original.

Comment: How many of those "nice" frameworks are actually nice though? For example, does Voice Over work when you are using them?

Comment: @AbhiBeckert What do you mean by Voice Over? As in speech-to-text or text-to-speech? If I do need those features, then you're right: I might have to deal with some platform-specific coding, but at least the GUI will be consistent across all, and my app will be mostly form based anyway. The key features I really need that require platform-specific work are camera access, file access, and GPS/location, for now. Those type of things don't really involve the GUI though and I will be calling native functions for those features.

Comment: VoiceOver is an alternative interface that allows visually impaired people to use your app without being able to see the screen, or perhaps they just have trouble seeing it (can't read, etc). If you use the native controls, all of these will work perfectly. If you write your own controls you have to implement it yourself. In my opinion, all apps (except for enterprise and games) should support VoiceOver. In some parts of the world it is probably required by law. I don't know how to make it work with OpenGL. AppKit lets you assign a string to every view (most views do it automagically)

Comment: Aaah, well, my app is mostly useless to blind people because it's meant for skateboarders. If I were making a general purpose app, then yeah, I'd probably use VoiceOver. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android uses a `GLSurfaceView` for all its OpenGL work. It ultimately inherits from the `View` class, so it's easy to use with other native views.

One idea might be to use a `FrameLayout` with both the `GLSurfaceView` and the other views in it. This is how they recommend doing camera overlays, so it shouldn't be any different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've decided instead it'd be better to implement my own version of Google Maps powered purely by OpenGL, which would make it cross-platform (except for Windows Phone's Direct3D platform). Another option would be to write it using HaxeNME, which *does* work all platforms including Windows Phone because HaxeNME has an option for rendering to HTML5 Canvas, and Canvas is 100% hardware-accelerated in Windows Phone 8.

Comment: I might add that Windows Phone 8 provides a native API through it's HTML5 web view too, from what I hear. So developing with HaxeNME on Windows Phone 8 might be very nice if canvas is indeed fully hardware-accelerated.